# mailto potential - what can i do with it?

Tags: javascript, html, mailto

Is it possible to embed html in a message body generated by a mailto link? And/or embed pictures or JavaScript as well? If yes, can you provide an example (it doesn't need to be encoded)?

Also, which other things can I do and which important things can't I do?

Comment: See the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247245/is-it-possible-to-add-an-html-link-in-the-body-of-a-mailto-link), note that the RFC linked to on that page has been obsoleted by [RFC 6068](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6068), which agrees that the `body` attribute is 'intended' for the plain text part of the email, although some user agents may use it differently (but they probably won't).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can!

```
mailto:info@rok-kralj.net?cc=someone@at.com&bcc=ccc&subject=test&body=%3Cb%3Etest%3C%2Fb%3E
```

You can post a lot in the body, you just have to escape tags with html entities, like `&gt; &lt; &quot;`. And I believe there is a URL length limit.

Oh, and don't forget to urlencode at the end!

Comment: Rok, can you provide an example where there is some text in bold in the body?

Comment: I believe it is like this:
mailto:info@rok-kralj.net?cc=someone@at.com&bcc=ccc&subject=test&body=%26lt%3Bb%26gt%3Bdddf%26lt%3B%2Fb%26gt%3B

Comment: also try `mailto:info@rok-kralj.net?cc=someone@at.com&bcc=ccc&subject=test&body=<b>test</b>`

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem to work: I just got raw text in my e-mail client. However, when I tried something like mailto:info@rok-kralj.net?cc=someone@at.com&bcc=ccc&subject=test&body=hello&lt;strong&gt;world it shows until the test part, so it seems that it is eating some html...

Comment: Hmm, tried with Outlook Express and Lotus Notes and none of them seem to work... So I'm just supposing that e-mail clients don't like the taste of html there

Comment: Let us try like this: `mailto:info@rok-kralj.net?cc=someone@at.com&bcc=ccc&subject=test&body=%3Cb%3Etest%3C%2Fb%3E` :) Have you noticed my second example? I will update the answer once you tell what works for you!

Comment: After all the testing I guess it is not anymore available due to security measures. Well, it still depends on the client. Some may still support it.