# how to configurate mailto to rtl?

Tags: javascript, html, outlook, ms-office, right-to-left

In my html I am writting:

```
 <a  href="mailto:fromJavaSceript@gmail.com?body=%A0%F9%ED%0D%0A%F9%ED%A0%EE%F9%F4%E7%E4%A0%0D%0A%FA%2E%E6%0D%0A%EE%F1%F4%F8%A0%F4%E5%EC%E9%F1%E4">websitemail@gmail.co.il </a>
```

the new outlook window TEXT is opened the from the left to the right where I want it to be opened from the right to the left

Comment: I seriously doubt you can control that from a browser link, especially across non-IE browsers. However there *might* be something that could work between IE and Outlook.

Comment: Wrap the body text in html and apply a style to it.

Comment: @George can you please show me an example , the message I write is In hebrew where the text is written from right to left , the data message is dispalyed in the outlook from the right to the left  therefore it's seemes odd that the change is in my html couse i want to change the outlook view...

Comment: You should note that the encoding here is in ISO_8859-8, or windows-1255, but not utf-8, which is what I was expecting to see originally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible.

See this question: [Is it possible to add an HTML link in the body of a MAILTO link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/247245/15456)

The answer there refers to [RFC 2368](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2368), whose second section reads, in part:

> The special hname "body" indicates that the associated hvalue is the
> body of the message. The "body" hname should contain the content for
> the first text/plain body part of the message. The mailto URL is
> primarily intended for generation of short text messages that are
> actually the content of automatic processing (such as "subscribe"
> messages for mailing lists), not general MIME bodies.

So, according to the standard, the body has to be in plain text.  That means that you're at the mercy of the client software: if it conforms to the standard, it will treat your body text like plain text, and behave in the default way.

I tried a lot of things on my local system (Outlook 2003), including changing my Normal.dot to be RTL, and configuring Outlook to use MS Word for new messages, and changing Outlook options to do everything RTL, but nothing worked, even as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the unicode "mirror" character in front of the text. In html &#8238; or url encoded %E2%80%AE

Comment: Sorry the unicode html entity didn't get encoded; messing up my post :-). Unicode has this character to indicate rtl content. If you put this in front of your content the text behind it is reversed.

Comment: StackOverfow doesn't like this :-P

Comment: @Gerben, is this actually working? cause it ain't workin for me....`&body=%E2%80%AEטקסט מיושר לימין`

Comment: Using U+202E (&#8238)That's a bad idea as it will override numbers, and embedded left to right text as well. A much more reasonable choice is to use U+200F (Right-to-left-mark).