# Insert HTML into mailto body

Tags: html, mailto

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to add an HTML link in the body of a MAILTO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247245/is-it-possible-to-add-an-html-link-in-the-body-of-a-mailto-link)

As I saw here:
[Is it possible to add an HTML link in the body of a MAILTO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247245/is-it-possible-to-add-an-html-link-in-the-body-of-a-mailto-link)

"However even if you use plain text it's possible that some modern mail clients would render the resulting link as a clickable link anyway, though."

How can I write mailto with HTML body that will work and will be parsed in
GMail or Outlook for example?

Comment: @Pekka ...seriously? -_-

Comment: @Mark well, what other course of action do you suggest? :)

Comment: Please re-read the accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247245/is-it-possible-to-add-an-html-link-in-the-body-of-a-mailto-link/247395#247395

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer to the question you link to states clearly that you can't have HTML in `mailto:` mails. And that's pretty much all there is to say about it.

Certain elements like links *may* get highlighted automatically by the mail client if it chooses to do so, but that doesn't mean HTML becomes possible in `mailto` E-Mails. Sorry.

Comment: what if you use replace?

Comment: @dave I dom't know what you mean.

Comment: str_replace('<br />', '%0D%0A',$stri); to replace html inside mailto with url encoding...