# Can I make an email link with rich default body?

Tags: html, email

It's easy to create a `mailto:` link in a webpage that opens the default mail client. You can even fill in some details, like subject and body. But can you also add images in the body? Or even full HTML email? Of course, it depends on the capabilities of the default mail client, but still...

Comment: After reading up on the subject. It seam this is unlikely to ever work as by default email clients have html emails turned off.

Comment: Really? As far as I've ever met them, they've all had HTML emails turned ON by default. But then I've not had very much experience in the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247245/is-it-possible-to-add-an-html-link-in-the-body-of-a-mailto-link) which referenced [RFC 2368](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2368) - no, it's not possible.

OK, sorry for wasting everyone's time. (Though that's the true purpose of StackOverflow anyway) :)