# send html content via outlook using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, mailto, rfc2368

I have one HTML page It contains table (it has three rows and two columns )

When i click button or link (anchor tag).

I need the same data in the outlook with the To(email id) &  Subject (any text)

is that possible to do in javascript

Regards
M

Comment: Would you mind to share your current code and would you mind to ask google for a javascript beginning tutorial and then for some advanced to give us your current javascript code to look where your error is instead doing your homework?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to add an HTML link in the body of a MAILTO link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247245/is-it-possible-to-add-an-html-link-in-the-body-of-a-mailto-link)

Comment: The short version is: no.  Per RFC 2368 that defines the mailto URI scheme.

Answer (score 0):

No, it would be a large security hole then.
Best way to make it is

```
<a href="mailto:whoever@whereever.com?subject=Type my subject here;body=Body of email document">Send email</a>
```

But it would work only if outlook is default mail agent on pc.

Comment: If you put a standard URL in the body, some email clients will be smart enough to read it as a link.

Comment: And still working with external environment from JS is restricted by security policy.

Comment: Which security policy would that be?

Comment: working with apps outside the browser, using that hack a little xss would cost you whole system compromised.

Comment: Even i tried it what the above code but it was not taking the HTML content.

Comment: It's pity, but such technic doesn't allow html content to be generated. According to rfs [rfc](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2368).