# Sending html emails with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a form (using only HTML and JavaScript) that sends emails. I want to insert a simple HTML table inside the body of the email. Something like this:

`<table border=1>
<tr><td>blabla</td></tr>
</table>`

After I click on the "Send" button a JavaScript function is called which sends the email via URL and the POST data appears in my email client - Outlook (which is okay for me) but there is a problem with the formatting. The data in *body* of the email is in plain text.

1. Is there any other way to do this only with JavaScript?
2. Is it necessary to use some kind of server-side scripts (like PHP or others) to format it properly?

Comment: Take a look at PHP heredocs

Comment: If you can set MIME type and content type, in other words if you can set header data, than you can do this without using server side code.

Comment: @Vladimir I'm using <form enctype="multipart/form-data"> if that's what you mean. I'm trying to avoid server-side code.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247245/is-it-possible-to-add-an-html-link-in-the-body-of-a-mailto-link/247395#247395

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript mailto function. Try this, hope it'll help you

```
<div id="mailBody"><table border=1> <tr><td>blabla</td></tr> </table></div>
<input type="button" onclick="sendMail();">
```

Under the script tag

```
function sendMail()
{
   var mailBody=document.getElementById('mailBody').innerHTML;
   window.location="mailto:yourmail@domain.com?subject=hii&body="+mailBody;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use only the java script to send HTML email try like below...

But i have **NOT Recommended** this type of Mail sending....

**Sending HTML Email by Javascript :**

```
function SendEmail()
{
    var outlookApp = new ActiveXObject("Outlook.Application");
    var nameSpace = outlookApp.getNameSpace("MAPI");
    mailFolder = nameSpace.getDefaultFolder(6);
    mailItem = mailFolder.Items.add('IPM.Note.FormA');
    mailItem.Subject = "Me";
    mailItem.To = "me@me.com";
    mailItem.HTMLBody = "<table border=1> <tr><td>blabla</td></tr> </table>";
    mailItem.display(0);
}
```

if you want to just send a email as plain text by javascript then try like below...

**Sending Plain Text by Javascript :**

```
window.open('mailto:test@example.com?subject=subject&body=Testing Email');
```

***Better you use a Server Side Coding to Send a email***

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer, but I imagine it's because this would only work when you've got both Internet Explorer and 0utlook, a limitation that you failed to mention.

Comment: It does not work on any *browser*, only on the pile of rubbish called Internet Explorer.

Answer (score -1):

What are the `<` characters are like in if you look at the source? if they are like `&#60;` or `&lt;` then you need to disable encoding on these. Also, you need to set formatting to HTML mail. Sorry I am not a *PHP* guy but I guess you will need server side code for that.

Comment: How can I disable the encoding? Is this something to do with the <form enctype> option?

Comment: did you look at the source to confirm the < characters are like the ones I said?

Comment: I tried with both < characters and did not work. I tried also with the appropriate url encoding for < (%3C)

Comment: Try @Tapas's answer. Sounds good to me..