# Sencha Touch - email button

Tags: javascript, email, sencha-touch-2, html-email, mailto

I need a mail button in my Android application, that opens a standard email form with filled To, Subject (can be edited) and Message fields. It's kind of a refer-a-friend email. How to make it?
All I've found is:

```
listeners: {
    tap: {
        fn: function() {
            console.log('button tapped');
            window.open('mailto:webmaster@example.com');
        },
        element: 'element'
    }
},
```

Unfortunately, I don't know how to implement html text and subject in it.

So, what's the solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try

`mailto:address@domain.com?Subject=subject&body=message`

but I'm not sure it works on every OS

Comment: Thank you for your reply! It works at least on Android device, but a little bit quirky - the intermediate window opens. But, what about body=<b>M</b>essage to display bold M? How to use html tags in there? Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247245/is-it-possible-to-add-an-html-link-in-the-body-of-a-mailto-link