# Send email that includes tables from the webpage into the body of the email

Tags: javascript, html, email

I was wondering if I can pass the tables on the webpage to the body of the email.  I was wondering if this was possible and if so point me in the right direction

My Button:

```
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT EMAIL TO: GNOC" <a 

href="mailto:myemail@whatever.com">
```

Table:

```
<table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" 

border="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td 

id="_invisibleIfEmpty" name="_invisibleIfEmpty" 

colspan="3" valign="top" width="100%"> 

<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" 

Title="loc:Header" ID="Header" 

FrameType="TitleBarOnly"/> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td 

 id="_invisibleIfEmpty" name="_invisibleIfEmpty" 

 rowspan="4" valign="top" height="100%"> 

 <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" 

 Title="loc:LeftColumn" ID="LeftColumn" 

FrameType="TitleBarOnly"/> </td>
                <td 

id="_invisibleIfEmpty" name="_invisibleIfEmpty" 

valign="top" height="100%"> <WebPartPages:WebPartZone 

runat="server" Title="loc:Row1" ID="Row1" 

FrameType="TitleBarOnly" Orientation="Horizontal"/> 

</td>
                <td 

id="_invisibleIfEmpty" name="_invisibleIfEmpty" 

rowspan="4" valign="top" height="100%"> 

<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" 

Title="loc:RightColumn" ID="RightColumn" 

FrameType="TitleBarOnly"/> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td 

id="_invisibleIfEmpty" name="_invisibleIfEmpty" 

valign="top" height="100%"> <WebPartPages:WebPartZone 

runat="server" Title="loc:Row2" ID="Row2" 

FrameType="TitleBarOnly" Orientation="Horizontal"/> 

</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td 

 id="_invisibleIfEmpty" name="_invisibleIfEmpty" 

 valign="top" height="100%"> <WebPartPages:WebPartZone 

 runat="server" Title="loc:Row3" ID="Row3" 

 FrameType="TitleBarOnly" Orientation="Horizontal"/> 

 </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td 

 id="_invisibleIfEmpty" name="_invisibleIfEmpty" 

 valign="top" height="100%"> <WebPartPages:WebPartZone 

runat="server" Title="loc:Row4" ID="Row4" 

FrameType="TitleBarOnly" Orientation="Horizontal"/> 

</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td 

  id="_invisibleIfEmpty" name="_invisibleIfEmpty" 

colspan="3" valign="top" width="100%"> 

<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" 

Title="loc:Footer" ID="Footer" 

FrameType="TitleBarOnly"/> </td>
            </tr>
            <script 

language="javascript">if(typeof

(MSOLayout_MakeInvisibleIfEmpty) == "function") 

{MSOLayout_MakeInvisibleIfEmpty();}</script>
    </table>
```

Goal: Import table from webform into email body

Comment: Don't think you can. It will be a string rather then HTML.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MailTo with HTML body](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620324/mailto-with-html-body)

Comment: But my outlook properties can switch into html mode so I dont understand why it cant take these tables?

Comment: Look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247245/is-it-possible-to-add-an-html-link-in-the-body-of-a-mailto-link

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible.

However, why don't you use an ajax call to send all the information in a table as if it were a form? On the separate php document you call to, use PHP's mail functionality (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

for example:

```
<form type="POST">
<table> <!-- This is your table -->
<tr>
<td>
Username
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="username" value="whateveruserentered" />
</td>
</tr>
<table>
```

So in the ajax method, you'd send username through. Then in the php page you called you'd say

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
Username
</td>
<td>
<?php echo $_POST['username']; ?>
</td>
</tr>
<table>
```

So you're recreating the table.

Put all of that in the body of the mail property, and off it goes. Fully fledged table just like on the original page.

In order to send the templated information you want to?