# Mailto: Add dynamic link to body

Tags: javascript, php, dynamic, share, mailto

I am setting up my share options in my php scrip and want to add a mailto: share function.  I use the following code to generate the current page url dynamically.  How do I encode or include this link in a mailto: body?

```
<a href="<?php echo JO_Request::getInstance()->getFullUrl(); ?>">
```

This is what I have tried:

```
<a href="mailto:?subject=mysubject&amp;body=someofmytextbeforeurl: href="<?php echo JO_Request::getInstance()->getFullUrl(); ?>">mail a friend</a>
```

Comment: mailto is for email, not a url.
your second link have twice the attribute href... something illegal in HTML.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to add an HTML link in the body of a MAILTO link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247245/is-it-possible-to-add-an-html-link-in-the-body-of-a-mailto-link)