# Does the Win 10 UWP EmailMessage API support having an HTML body?

Tags: html, email, windows-runtime, c++-cx, uwp

I have tried the following code to send an email from an Universal Windows Platform app. It works fine when I use **EmailMessageBodyKind::PlainText**. However, as indicated in the code below, **EmailMessageBodyKind::Html** seems to launch the email client with no content. Does anyone know what else needs to be set to get this to work - the documentation is sparse 8 (

```
using namespace Windows::Storage::Streams;
using namespace Windows::ApplicationModel::Email;
using namespace Windows::Security::Cryptography;
auto bin = CryptographicBuffer::ConvertStringToBinary(
    L"<html><body>this <b>is</b> text</body></html>",
    BinaryStringEncoding::Utf16LE);
auto memStream = ref new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
concurrency::create_task(memStream->WriteAsync(bin)).then(
    [memStream](unsigned)
    {
        auto email = ref new EmailMessage();
        email->To->Append(ref new EmailRecipient(L"test@gmail.com"));
        email->Subject = L"Email Report";
        auto randomAccessStreamReference = RandomAccessStreamReference::CreateFromStream(memStream);
        email->SetBodyStream(EmailMessageBodyKind::Html, randomAccessStreamReference);
        EmailManager::ShowComposeNewEmailAsync(email);
    }
);
```

Comment: maybe you need to re-set the seek pointer after you write to the stream.

Comment: Yeah - i had tried that - but unfortunately adding memStream->Seek(0); (prior to the EmailManager::ShowComposeNewEmailAsync(email); call of course) has no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I got some bad news for you.

**It is not possible to do so using `EmailManager.ShowComposeNewEmailAsync`**

Regarding using `SetBodyStream` with `EmailMessageBodyKind.Html`, we have this [from MSDN forum:](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8125da13-7d79-4a5a-82a5-57c8a322be78/uwp10240c-emailmessage-with-emailmessagebodykindhtml?forum=wpdevelop)

> Currently, the EmailMessageBodyKind.Html won't work for create a new
> HTML e-mail and there is no other way as a workaround, I've checked
> the internal resource, this API is used for populating messages from
> App server and save e-mail message into local folder.

The thing is: `EmailManager.ShowComposeNewEmailAsync` uses `mailto` to send the message and, as stated in [some other question already answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/247395/4905310):

> Section 2 of [RFC 2368](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2368) says that the body field is supposed to be in
> text/plain format, so you can't do HTML.
>
> However even if you use plain text it's possible that some modern mail
> clients would render the resulting link as a clickable link anyway,
> though.

That being said, you're relying on the mail client to render that HTML for you.
I've tested this using Windows 10 Mail Client, Gmail and Outlook (both the later on a web browser), and all of them failed to render a simple HTML `<b>` tag on the mail body, showing it as plain text instead.

Now, for the alternatives (from [that same MSDN forum thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8125da13-7d79-4a5a-82a5-57c8a322be78/uwp10240c-emailmessage-with-emailmessagebodykindhtml?forum=wpdevelop)):

> Note that if I use the ShareDataContract (DataTransferManager), I am
> able to set the HTML in the request and it will appear in the email
> body if the user chooses to share via Mail. However I would like to
> skip the Share UI and go directly with composing an email with
> recipient already populated, HTML body, and image attachments.
>
> One alternative is to persist the HTML body to a file and then include
> that file as an additional attachment, however that is not ideal

**The `DataTransferManager` successfully formatted the HTML message.** Here's a small sample of how your sample code would look like, adapted [from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh973055?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-10):

```
void YourView::ShareHtml()
{
    DataTransferManager^ dataTransferManager = DataTransferManager::GetForCurrentView();
    auto dataRequestedToken = dataTransferManager->DataRequested += 
        ref new TypedEventHandler<DataTransferManager^, DataRequestedEventArgs^>(
            this, &YourView::OnShareHtml);
    DataTransferManager::ShowShareUI();
}

void YourView::OnShareHtml(DataTransferManager^ sender, DataRequestedEventArgs^ e)
{
    DataRequest^ request = e->Request;
    request->Data->Properties->Title = "Email Report";

    String^ html = L"<html><body>this <b>is</b> text</body></html>";
    String^ htmlFormat = HtmlFormatHelper::CreateHtmlFormat(html);
    request->Data->SetHtmlFormat(htmlFormat);
}
```

The limitations of this approach are:

1. You cannot force the user to select e-mail as the sharing option
2. You cannot previously specify the mail recipient.