# Opening mail client with formatted text in desktop & iPad

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, email, outlook

I am working on a functionality "Share Link" in which I have to open a mail client and pass a link.
I tried two ways,one is this way :

```
Window.location.href = "mailto:user@example.com?subject=Subject&body=message%20goes%20here";
```

but the issue with this approach is we can't share text as a hyperlink.

Other way is genrating eml files from C#,but that is not acceptable way since user has to download en eml file and then open it.

Is there any way to pass an hyperlink in mail body in any mail client on different devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247245/is-it-possible-to-add-an-html-link-in-the-body-of-a-mailto-link):

> Section 2 of [RFC 2368](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2368) says that the body field is supposed to be
> in text/plain format, so you can't do HTML.
>
> However even if you use plain text it's possible that some modern mail
> clients would render the resulting link as a clickable link anyway,
> though.