# open a HTML code in outlook in java

Tags: java, outlook

I have to open a html code in outlook instead of sending the email. I need to open the content in outlook first and then provide a option to user to edit it if he wants.

I want user to sent the email manually. I just want to display the information in outlook mail and then user can sent it manually.

sample html content:

```
<HTML>
<body>
  <b>Hello test</b>
</body>
</HTML>
```

The above html I need to open in the outlook mail.

Code:

```
    System.out.println("Gettjg in");
    String recipientName = null;
    System.out.println("receiver"+receiver.toString());
    // Prepare the evaluation context
    final Context ctx = new Context(locale);
    ctx.setVariable("name", recipientName);
    ctx.setVariable("remedyGroup", recipientName);
    ctx.setVariable("regards", recipientName);
    ctx.setVariable("assigneeName", recipientName);
    ctx.setVariable("assigneeGroup", recipientName);
    ctx.setVariable("subscriptionDate", new Date());
    ctx.setVariable("hobbies", Arrays.asList("Cinema", "Sports", "Music"));

    // Prepare message using a Spring helper
    final MimeMessage mimeMessage = this.mailSender.createMimeMessage();
    final MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, "UTF-8");
    message.setSubject(receiver.getTicketSummary());
    message.setFrom("thymeleaf@example.com");
    message.setTo(receiver.getReceiverEmail());

    // Create the HTML body using Thymeleaf
    final String htmlContent = this.templateEngine.process("email-simple.html", ctx);
    message.setText(htmlContent, true /* isHtml */);
    try {
        Desktop.getDesktop().mail( new URI( "mailto:bsenthilnathan@cognizant.com?subject="+message+"&cc="+"fsf"+"&body="+htmlContent));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I am not sure how can I open a html content in the outlook. Can anybody knows how to open the HTML content in a outlook instead of sending it.

Comment: Please elaborate `open a html content`. Not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: need to open the content in outlook first and then provide a option to user to edit it if he wants

Comment: I am not able to open the html information in outlook

Comment: @Sujeet Sinha I just elaborate the  html content

Comment: any idea how can I achieve using java

Comment: I'm unaware of any workaround at the moment :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you are using simply opens any mail client present on the user machine with the parameters sent in the URI component. If you check the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247245/is-it-possible-to-add-an-html-link-in-the-body-of-a-mailto-link), you cannot send HTML content using this method unfortunately!