# Adding a link in the body of mail_to - Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am unsure how to add a link to the body of mail_to.

> i would like to make @social.title (BGF Ventures: the truth about
>   fundraising) a link, so when clicked the user is directed to the page
>   of the event/social.

Is this possible? if so, could one advise me how

i have the below code:

```
<span>
<%= mail_to '', '', class: "fa fa-envelope", 
                  subject: "#{@social.title}", 
                  body: "Hi, would like to invite you to the social '#{@social.title}'" %>
</span>
```

[image]

Comment: read this discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247245/is-it-possible-to-add-an-html-link-in-the-body-of-a-mailto-link . You can't put html there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not something Rails can handle if its not handled from javascript in the first place, as this helper will be translated to HTML (some of helpers with javascript support) so Short answer No, you can't

Check also: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247245/is-it-possible-to-add-an-html-link-in-the-body-of-a-mailto-link)
Section 2 of [RFC 2368](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2368) says that the `body` field is supposed to be in `text/plain` format, so you can't do HTML.

However even if you use plain text it's possible that some modern mail clients would render the resulting link as a clickable link anyway, though.

Answer (score 1):

With mail_to link this seems to be impossible for most mail clients(read my comment). Do you have to use a mail_to link? (this opens the user's default mailbox which may or may not be what you need). If not, you can generate this email on the server side and that way you will have full control (and will be able to put that link among other things).

Answer (score 1):

In general, no, you cannot add an anchor in `mailto:`'s `body`. But I suggest to read [this URL](http://www.angelfire.com/dc/html-webmaster/mailto.htm), especially the section with title **html mailto forms**. If you can somehow generate the form, that can do the trick.

Alternatively, you can add a full link (the one which starts with http(s)) to the body, and many of today's email client will detect it and make it clickable.