# How to place hyperlink or onClick event in email body

Tags: javascript, html, href

I have to open a email window in which I need to provide one hyperlink and one onClick event in boday.

Here is my code.

```
ClickEmail : function (){
    var Subject = "Test";
    var body = "";
    body = body + "   Name1  " + record.name[0] + "%0D%0A";
    MyRecord  == window.location.href = 'mailto:?subject=Subject :'+Subject+'&body=My Body'+body 
}
```

Can anybody please explain me what I need to do for that.

Comment: Please check this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247245/is-it-possible-to-add-an-html-link-in-the-body-of-a-mailto-link

Answer (score 5):

You need to modify your `body` to include the hyperlink. Example: `var body = "<a href='somelink'>Link title</a>";`

You cannot add functions (your `onClick` event) to emails.

Comment: This link is not clickable. What I need to mention there. Thanks for answer It works but not clickable

Comment: @shankysingh then the problem maybe that you are sending a plain text email and not an HTML email. In that case you need to update your question.

Comment: I am sending exactly what I written in code. Wait let me figure it out the solution for that. Then I will accept your answer. Thanks for all

Answer (score -1):

You can try to create an `<a>` tag element with `href="mailto:abc@exmaple.com"`, then call the click event on javascript on that `<a>` tag

For exmaple:

```
function mailTo(mailAddr){
    var aTag = document.createElement("a");
    aTag.href = "mailto:" + mailAddr;
    aTag.target = "_blank";
    aTag.id = "openMailClient";
    aTag.innerHTML = " ";
    aTag.click();
}
```

Try: https://jsfiddle.net/ogqwu1j2/