# HTML table in reply mail

Tags: html, email, outlook

We require the users to reply in a specific format about their problems. Our current application sends an auto-generated mail which has a mailto embedded like this

`<a href="mailto:Team_DL?subject=Issue regarding {copy_of_autogen_mail_sub}&body=Describe your problem in detail here.">Contact Application Team</a>`

What we want now is to include a table in the embedded "mailto" so that user can describe their problems in much better way. We have tried encoding html inside mailto body, but it gets treated as simple text.

Is there any way to include the table in the mailto body or any better way to improve the interaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to include HTML in the mailto body, as defined in Section 2 of [RFC 2368](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247245/is-it-possible-to-add-an-html-link-in-the-body-of-a-mailto-link/247395#247395).

Possible alternate solutions:

1. Have users type their information into an HTML form and then use [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) (or similar server side language) to send the email
2. Try to format your email a little bit nicer by adding in some line breaks. You can use `%0D` (Carriage Return) followed by `%0A` (Line Feed). Maybe something like this:
   `<a href="mailto:Team_DL?subject=Issue regarding {copy_of_autogen_mail_sub}&body=System Affected:%0D%0ADate of Issue:%0D%0ADescription:%0D%0A">Contact Application Team</a>`